# Especificação e Implementação Java Socket

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, socket, herança, interface

Eu criei uma classe `MySocket` que `extends java.net.Socket`, porém eu vi que a classe `java.net.Socket` implementa a interface `java.io.Closeable`, e a minha pergunta é: Na minha classe `MySocket` sou obrigado a implementar também a interface `Closeable`, ou por ser filha da classe `java.net.Socket` ela automaticamente já implementa `Closeable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende do que fez na sua classe. Eu diria que provavelmente não, acredito que o que foi implementado na classe mãe seja suficiente, não acho que precisa fazer algo mais. Mas se precisa fazer algo específico para a sua classe no momento de fechar, aí terá que sobrepor o `close()` na sua classe, fazendo o que precisa e chamando o `super.close()`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!